# PHP loop pulling from SQL (beginner)

Tags: php, html, sql, database

new to php and sql, and struggling for resources.

Essentially all I need to do is SELECT data from a table and to format it in appropriate html.

I've got the general idea, just not setting up the loop.
I have the SQL connection set up to the databse and then to the table.

here is the code. http://pastebin.com/vdTJgU5z
and the layout of the table.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNsrV.png

Thanks guys, if there's anything that seems way off let me know, because i'd rather correct it now rather than later down the track.

CODE:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablenamehere");
while(????){
$game = $temp['game'];
$stance = $temp['stance'];
$start = $temp['start'];
}
echo '<div  id="accordion">
       <h3> echo $game $stance $start  </td></h3>
       </div>';
```

Comment: Paste your code here, not in pastebin.

Comment: Correction: paste your code in both; you want answers, those that are willing to help have preferences

Comment: The php manual has examples that cover your exact question.  Have you looked through it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We all suggest the use of PDO for your MySQL connectivity.

Here's a quick and *dirty* way to get started (not tested):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbtest;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // all pdo errors will throw an exception

try {
  $result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
  while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "  <td>" . $row['column_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "  <td>" . $row['column_name2'] . "</td>";
    echo "  <td>" . $row['column_name3'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Something went wrong with the query. {$e->getMessage()}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at the PHP manual

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

It is pretty straightforward once you get the hang of it and understand what it is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablenamehere");
while($query){
$game = $query['game'];
$stance = $query['stance'];
$start = $query['start'];

echo "<div  id='accordion'>
       <h3><tr><td>".$game."</td><td>".$stance."</td><td>".$start."</td></tr></h3>  
       </div>";

}
```